# how to use interpolating functions to smoothly paint a polygon?

Tags: graphics, color, interpolation

consider 4 different colors on the nodes (with different parameter values) how to interpolate  when the color values are given on the nodes using the constructed interpolation functions to paint the quadrilateral?

```
localCoordinates={{-(5/4), -(3/2)}, {3/4, -(3/2)}, {7/4, 7/2}, {-(5/4), -(1/2)}};

deltaNa=((7 + 8 x - 6 y) (-21 + 20 x - 4 y))/(4 (169 + 80 x + 6 y));

deltaNb=-((5 (5 + 4 x) (7 + 8 x - 6 y))/(4 (169 + 80 x + 6 y)));

deltaNc=-((11 (5 + 4 x) (3 + 2 y))/(4 (169 + 80 x + 6 y)));

deltaNd=-((3 (3 + 2 y) (21 - 20 x + 4 y))/(4 (169 + 80 x + 6 y)));
```

Above are my interpolating functions for each node;
A, B, C, D is in the order of local Coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!